# Odd regular expression result... / character

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have this regular expression in objective-c

```
NSString* searchString = [searchBlock stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<(.*?)>" withString:@"" options: NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange (0, [searchBlock length])];
```

The code should remove everything that comes between pointy brackets <>  and it seems to work most of the time but seems to fail on this case and I'm not sure why:

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/starkpo">
        <img height="120" width="124" alt="Follow us @starkpo." style="border: 0;"
        src="http://www.thestarkingtonpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/twitter-master.jpg" 
        title="Join us on Twitter" />
    </a>
    <p style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 17px; margin: 0; padding: 0 4px 5px;">Follow us @starkpo.</p></div>
```

returns:

```
<img height="120" width="124" alt="Follow us @starkpo." style="border: 0;"
        src="http://www.thestarkingtonpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/twitter-master.jpg" 
        title="Join us on Twitter" />

    Follow us @starkpo.
```

The expected answer is simply to return the plain text: Follow us @starkpo.

Any idea why it seems to be ignoring the self closing tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the regex engine to make `.` match newlines as well.

Add [`NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSRegularExpressionOptions) to `options`.

Comment: as a note in case anyone else is reading this. This flag is not part of NSString. To make this work I have to create an actual NSRegularExpression.

Answer (score 1):

`.` does not match newlines by default.

You can enable this using the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` flag.